# How to print an empty line in swift

Tags: swift, line

It seems to be a simple question but I cannot find the answer from the web. I want to print an empty line in Swift. I tried `print("\n")` but it actually prints two empty lines. I tried `print()` but I get a complier error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print("this is some text")
print("")
print("this is the end")
```

It **is** simple...

Output:

```
this is some text

this is the end
```

Comment: Oh, yeah thanks. I didn't think about an empty string.